# C++ concatenation and strinization operator

Tags: c++, macros, string-concatenation

I would like to make a shortcut for making similar function calls

```
int g[2];

void f1() {
   g[0] = 1;
}

void f2() {
  g[1] = 2;
}

void (*f)();
```

Since functions f1, f2 have some common pattern, can I make a shortcut through C++ concatenation (##) and strinization (#) operator or something else to have something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   // have to do something to get the function name formed like f1, f2
   // and then assign f to f1 or f2 and call f, based on value of i
   // need help in this portion
}
```

Comment: But why not pass the index as a regular parameter to the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<size_t i>
void f()
{
    g[i-1] = i;
}

f<1>();
f<2>();
```

Comment: Is there a downside to using templates here rather than just using a `size_t` parameter? For each function call you're generating a new function entirely. Is there a reason you chose to use templates?

Comment: @0x499602D2 The OP didn't give much to go on. But if he had X nearly identical functions anyway, what's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following approach by using an array of function pointers

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   void ( *pf[] )() = { f1, f2 };
   pf[i]();
}
```